# How to get contour auto label coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib, coordinates, contour, cartopy

How can I retrieve the automatically determined contour label coordinates in the example below?

matplotlib example from [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/contour_demo.html)

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


delta = 0.025
x = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, delta)
y = np.arange(-2.0, 2.0, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = np.exp(-X**2 - Y**2)
Z2 = np.exp(-(X - 1)**2 - (Y - 1)**2)
Z = (Z1 - Z2) * 2

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
CS = ax.contour(X, Y, Z)
CS_labels = ax.clabel(CS, inline=True, fontsize=10)
ax.set_title('Simplest default with labels')
```

[image]

I would like to do something like

```
label_locations = CS_labels.get_label_coords()
```

So that I can start with an auto-selected set and modify manually as needed. This would be especially helpful when dealing with [labels in geospatial coordinates](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/gallery/contour_labels.html).

**Update:**
The solution provided by swatchai works for both matplotlib and cartopy.

```
for txobj in CS.labelTexts:
    pos = txobj.get_position()
    txt = txobj.get_text()
    print(pos, txt)
```

Label positions are best retrieved from the `CS` object, instead of the `CS_labels` object.

**Note:**
tdy's solution only works for matplotlib, but not when using cartopy GeoAxes, as `ax.clabel()` returns `'NoneType'` for `CS_labels` so `CS_labels[0].get_position()` cannot be accessed that way.

Comment: Related matplotlib question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19418901/get-coordinates-from-the-contour-in-matplotlib

Helpful, but unrelated, cartopy contour question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61032307/matplotlib-cartopy-solid-fill-underneath-contour-plot

Answer (score 1):

For cartopy, once you created contour labels, you can get access to the labels by

```
CS.labelTexts  #CS is contour_collection set
```

Here is the runnable code that demonstrates all the steps.

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy
import numpy as np

delta = 0.025
x = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, delta)
y = np.arange(-2.0, 3.0, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = np.exp(-X**2 - Y**2)*20
Z2 = np.exp(-(X - 1)**2 - (Y - 1)**2)*20
Z = (Z1 - Z2) * 2

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())

CS = ax.contour(X, Y, Z)

ax.clabel(
    CS,
    colors=['black'],
    manual=False,
    inline=True,
    fmt=' {:.0f} '.format
)

ax.set_extent([-3,3,-2,3])
ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

[image: contourplot]

To list the contour label texts:-

```
CS.labelTexts
```

Output:

```
[Text(1.003030188944607, 0.7749999999999897, ' -30 '),
 Text(1.4249999999999843, 1.7059169688922102, ' -20 '),
 Text(0.30880609807150927, 0.9499999999999895, ' -10 '),
 Text(0.6000000000000081, 0.3999999999999915, ' 0 '),
 Text(-0.7000000000000091, -0.9440944811557408, ' 10 '),
 Text(-0.12500000000001066, -0.8102372655970758, ' 20 '),
 Text(-0.050000000000010925, 0.24709487906649752, ' 30 ')]
```

To print position and text of each label:-

```
for txobj in CS.labelTexts:
    pos = txobj.get_position()
    txt = txobj.get_text()
    print(pos, txt)
```

The output:

```
(1.003030188944607, 0.7749999999999897)  -30 
(1.4249999999999843, 1.7059169688922102)  -20 
(0.30880609807150927, 0.9499999999999895)  -10 
(0.6000000000000081, 0.3999999999999915)  0 
(-0.7000000000000091, -0.9440944811557408)  10 
(-0.12500000000001066, -0.8102372655970758)  20 
(-0.050000000000010925, 0.24709487906649752)  30
```

If you want to manipulate each of the labels, the methods `.set_text()` and `.set_position()` are often used.